# Integration tests start spring for every test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, maven-failsafe-plugin

My application is a spring-boot application with maven. It starts spring-boot for every integration test when I run `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

I found the peril after hours of googling and investigation.
It is because of the configuration of the `maven-failsafe-plugin`. The `reuseFork` is false in my pom.xml. I resolved the situation by removing the `reuseFork`(It is trure by default).
LOL.